# Customisable business network

Tags: networking, social-networks, business-card

Who can suggest a business network software that helps in connecting two types of users in specific sector, for example vendors and sellers of specific product or service, I don't need cart based system, or product gallery one, what I care about is the users profiles, and the interaction between them, just as a business network. It should just be very customisable even on code level.

Whether open source or commercial, both options are okay.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn or Facebook can keep the kind of info you describe.
What matters is how are you going to build that network?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code, then you can start off with one of the drupal distributions for collaboration/communities like:

https://www.drupal.org/project/social

https://www.drupal.org/project/commons

These are opensource solutions, but you have to host the site yourself. Not clear whether you are looking for self-hosting or an existing service.

But you can also use LinkedIn to probably achieve what you want too.